# Delphi XE5 Android Samples Assistance

Tags: android, delphi

I downloaded the 30 day trial of Delphi XE5 yesterday, I've been using Delphi 7 for many years. I want to look at producing Android apps and I am very enthused by the potential for XE5. I could do with a little help just to get me going.

So, I downloaded the Samples provided at http://www.embarcadero.co.uk/products/delphi/android-ios-code-samples-xe5#gyroscope and focused on the Gyroscope Sample.

I can load the Gyroscope project into Delphi XE5.
I can compile it with no errors. ;-)
I can set the Build to Release.
I can set the Target Platforms to Android.
I can go through the Deploy process.
After all that I can end up with a 5MB(wow!) APK file.

The next thing that I wanted to do was get that APK transferred to, and installed on, my device - which is a Motorola Xoom tablet. The tablet is running ICS 4.0.4 and has "Unknown source" checked so that I can work with apps that aren't from the Play Store.

When I try to install the Gyroscope APK on the tablet, the popup telling me what permissions it wants and asking me whether I want to "install this application?" appears. When I click on "Install" it briefly says "Installing..." then "Application not installed".

I realise this is a Delphi XE5 101 question - but can someone please let me know if there is an obvious step in the process of getting an app onto a device that I might be missing?

I confirm that I can install other APKs that aren't from the Google Play Store on the Xoom. I've not yet tried another Delphi XE5 Sample... thought I would ask this question first. I appreciate any guidance offered.

Comment: I gave 2 other Samples a go - Accelerometer and PlayAudioFile - and the good news is that they compile and deploy and I get APKs. I can then move those APKs to the Motorola Xoom and they successfully install. However, when ran, they produce a simple black screen for about a second or so, then return to the previous screen.

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour with the VideoPlayback Sample as well. I believe I am now at the point where I can choose a Sample, compile it, deploy it, get an APK installed onto the device, but it won't run - black screen - then back to previous. Is there something I am not doing? Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I went with the new Android Studio instead... I'll try to learn my App-making that way. My first app deployed to my Xoom in around 2 hours after install yesterday and the APK came out at a more reasonable 715KB. I don't know what Delphi XE5 is really trying to achieve, but even the Samples provided by the company that sell the product don't seem to work out of the box... how can they be properly used as learning assets?

Comment: The deployment step from the Delphi IDE should, in addition to compiling and linking the code, also deploy the APK to the device and begin a debug session while running the code. Clearly, your setup isn't yet complete. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development#Preparing_Your_Android_Development_Environment

Comment: XE5 was released in 2013. There have been a lot of improvements in Delphi Android development in the last 6 years! I'd like to suggest you obtain a later release of the Delphi IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> I can set the Target Platforms to Android

This is not enough. 
Additionally you need to open Project Options, navigate to Deployment\Provisioning and generate new `KeyStore` file.

"**Application not installed**" error means that you try to install unsigned .apk file.